# Argument value not being passed while creating class object in PHP

Tags: php, function, constructor, arguments, default

I am new to PHP and am facing the below issue. There are two files:

In the first PHP file I am writing the below code to create an object

```
$oNotas = new gcibjdnf($sFiltro, false,'apcconc.nm_apelido', $bBuscarPorChassi);
```

In the second file-gcibjdnf.php, I have the below code for the constructor

```
public function __construct($sFiltro = '', $bPaginar = false, $sOrdem= 'apcconc.nm_apelido, danfe', $bBuscarPorChassi = false) {

...}
```

However, 
when I print `$sOrdem` from the gcibjdnf.php file, I am getting `"apcconc.nm_apelido, danfe"` as an output.

According to me it should print `"apcconc.nm_apelido"`. But it is printing the default parameter instead of the value passed.

I am using PHP 5.6 version. Please let me know in case anyone has any idea on this.

Comment: Your going to need to show more code. As far as I can tell you are doing nothing with the values passed in.

Comment: Probably a typo in the setter.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/v4BdI